# Clustering is not working on DeckGL using Super Cluster

Tags: javascript, dictionary, mapbox, cluster-analysis, deck.gl

I've implemented custering using deckgl and super cluster. I'm using IconLayer, GeoJsonLayer, ScatterplotLayer, and TextLayer.

```js
addAssetMonitoringIconsLayer () {

        const getIconSize = (size) => {
            return Math.min(100, size) / 100 + 1;
        }

        class IconClusterLayer extends CompositeLayer {
            shouldUpdateState({changeFlags}) {
                return changeFlags.somethingChanged;
            }

            updateState({props, oldProps, changeFlags}) {
                const rebuildIndex = changeFlags.dataChanged || props.sizeScale !== oldProps.sizeScale;

                if (rebuildIndex) {
                    const index = new Supercluster({maxZoom: 16, radius: props.sizeScale});

                    index.load(
                        props.data.map(d => ({
                            geometry: {coordinates: props.getPosition(d)},
                            properties: d,
                        })
                    ));
                    this.setState({index});
                }

                const z = Math.floor(this.context.viewport.zoom);
                if (rebuildIndex || z !== this.state.z) {
                    this.setState({
                        data: this.state.index.getClusters([-180, -85, 180, 85], z),
                        z,
                    });
                }
            }

            renderLayers() {
                const {data} = this.state;

                return [

                    // No clustering -> render icons from the API -> onHover: show the asset name -> on Click: show the asset details
                    new IconLayer(
                        this.getSubLayerProps({
                            id: 'icon',
                            data,
                            getPosition: d => d.geometry.coordinates,
                            getIcon: d => d.properties.cluster ? '' : {url: (BASE_URL).substring(0, BASE_URL.length) + d.properties.icon_url, width: 38, height: 60, anchorY: 60},
                            transitions: {getPosition: { duration: 100 }},
                            onHover: (info, d) => {
                                if (!d.properties.cluster && (info.coordinate && info.object)){
                                    const marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({
                                        position: { lat: info.coordinate[1], lng: info.coordinate[0] },
                                        map: this.map.current.context[MAP]
                                    });
                                    marker.setOptions({ 'opacity': 0.0 });
                                    marker.setOptions({ 'title': `${info.object.asset_model__name}` });
                                        
                                    marker.addListener("click", () => {
                                        this.showMarkerInfo(info.object);
                                    });
                                }
                            },
                            onClick: (info, d) => {
                                if (!d.properties.cluster){
                                    this.showMarkerInfo(info.object);
                                }
                            },
                        })
                    ),

                    // when there is clustering show this and change it's size on zoom change -> onHover -> show total number of assets in the cluster
                    new ScatterplotLayer(
                        this.getSubLayerProps({
                            id: 'scatter-plot-cluster-layer',
                            data,
                            getPosition: d => d.geometry.coordinates,
                            getRadius: d => getIconSize(d.properties.cluster ? (d.properties.point_count * 200) : 0),
                            getFillColor: [255, 0, 0],
                            opacity: 0.5,
                            radiusScale: 6,
                            radiusMinPixels: 20,
                            radiusMaxPixels: 100,
                            transitions: {
                                getRadious: {
                                    duration: 1000,
                                    enter: t => t * 1.1,
                                }
                            },
                            onHover: (info, d) => {
                                if (!d.properties.cluster && (info.coordinate && info.object)){
                                    const marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({
                                        position: { lat: info.coordinate[1], lng: info.coordinate[0] },
                                        map: this.map.current.context[MAP]
                                    });
                                    marker.setOptions({ 'opacity': 0.0 });
                                    marker.setOptions({ 'title': `${d.properties.point_count}` });
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    ),

                    // when clustered, show to the total number of assets in the cluster on top of ScatterplotLayer
                    new TextLayer (
                        this.getSubLayerProps({
                            id: 'scatter-plot-cluster-layer',
                            data,
                            getText: d => d.properties.cluster ? d.properties.point_count : '',
                            getSize: 12,
                            getColor: [255, 255, 255],
                            characterSet: 'auto',
                        })
                    )
                ]
            }
        }

        // All the data that are necessary to create clustering and plotting point assets
        const layer = {
            id: "icon-cluster",
            data: this.props.assetMonitoringIconsData,
            pickable: true,
            getPosition: (d) => {
                if(d.geom && d.geom.coordinates) {
                    return d.geom.coordinates;
                }
                return d.geom;
            },
            sizeScale: 60,
            dataTransform: (data) => {
                return data.results.map(res => {
                    if(res.geom && res.geom_type === 'POINT' && res.geom) {
                        res.geom = {
                            "type": "Point",
                            "coordinates": [
                                res.geom.lng,
                                res.geom.lat
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                    return res;
                });
            }
        }

        const layers = this.overlay.current.props.layers
            ? [new IconClusterLayer(layer)].concat(this.overlay.current.props.layers.filter((ele) => ele.id !== layer.id))
            : [new IconClusterLayer(layer)];
        
        if (this.overlay.current) {
            this.overlay.current.setMap(this.map.current.context[MAP]);
            this.overlay.current.setProps({
                layers
            });
        }
    }

    addAssetMonitoringGeoJsonLayer () {
        const layer = {
            id: "custom-GeoJson-layer",
            data: this.props.assetMonitoringIconsData,
            pickable: true,
            stroked: true,
            filled: false,
            lineWidthScale: 20,
            getLineColor: [160, 160, 180, 200],
            getLineWidth: 1,
            wrapLongitude: true,
            dataTransform: (data) => {
                return data.results.map(res => {
                    if(res.geom && res.geom_type === 'LINESTRING') {
                        if (res.geom) {
                            res.geom = {
                                "type": "MultiLineString",
                                "coordinates": res.geom,
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return res;
                });
            }
        }

        const layers = this.overlay.current.props.layers
            ? [new GeoJsonLayer(layer)].concat(this.overlay.current.props.layers.filter((ele) => ele.id !== layer.id))
            : [new GeoJsonLayer(layer)];
        
        if (this.overlay.current) {
            this.overlay.current.setMap(this.map.current.context[MAP]);
            this.overlay.current.setProps({
                layers
            });
        }
    }
```

The data from `addAssetMonitoringGeoJsonLayer()` is being passed to the `addAssetMonitoringIconsLayer()` but the data is not available to the `renderLayers()`.

The console is throughing the following errors.

````
deck: update of CompositeLayer({id: 'icon-cluster'}): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getClusters')

deck: update of CompositeLayer({id: 'icon-cluster'}): undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))```
````